# Как сделать регулярное выражение для номеров Украины на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

регулярка для проверки номера телефонов Украины

+38 (www) www-ww-ww

могут быть -, как разделитель, а может не быть

```
def is_valid_phone(self):
    pattern=r"/^\+38\d({3})\d{3}\d{2}\d{2}$/"
    phone_re=re.compile(pattern)
    if phone_re.findall(self.phone): return True
    else: return False
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что текст регулярки взят из php :)

Comment: Так и есть. Плохо понимаю регулярки

Comment: В php, как я понял, единственная причина писать `//` (или `@@`) в регулярках, чтобы передавать флаги, типа: `/[a-z]+/i`. В питоне флаги можно передавать как параметр, например: `re.search('...', '...', flags=re.I)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сначала удалил из строки, всё, что не относится к числам, после начал извлекать значения:

- `re.sub` удалил все символы, что не относятся к цифрам
- `re.search` сделает поиск по шаблону, если найдет, то вернет объект `Match`, иначе `None`. А `bool` для объекта `Match` вернет `True`, а для `None` вернет `False`, поэтому тут можно обойтись без проверок

Например:

```
def is_valid_phone(self) -> bool:
    text = re.sub(r'\D', '', self.phone)
    return bool(re.search(r"^38\d{10}$", text))
```

Но если строго подходить к формату строки, тогда:

```
def is_valid_phone(self) -> bool:
    return bool(re.search(r"^\+38 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{2}$", self.phone))
```